# Want to attach databasename with current date and time

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I want to create a Database in sqlite using python. My concerns is that as i run my script the database name must be anyname+the 'date and time' at the time of creation. For instance if i run the script at 4pm. Database name must be deep02072018:04:00:00

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: I created a python scrip for scrapping the data and store it into database.I want at the time of runing my script database name must be associated with the current time. For instance if my database name is 'ABC' so when i execute the script the time is associated with 'ABC' like 'ABC_0307201807:35:50'

Comment: Sure, but what part of that are you stuck on? Getting the time as a string? Concatenating it to another string? Opening a database with a specific name? Do you have code that's giving you an error? If so, can you show the code and the error?

Comment: Actually i am initiating database connection like this, print('Please select in which language you want to Store the data')
choiceUrl = input('ENTER 1 for German and 2 for French  : ')
choiceUrl = int(choiceUrl)
if choiceUrl==1:
    soup = make_soup("https://sat_de_lst_pdt.jsp?sel=_")
    create_connection('Gagan\DataBase\ger.db')
    #conn=sqlite3.connect('Gagan\German.db')
else:
    soup = make_soup("https://sat_fr_lst_pdt.jsp?sel=_")  
    conn=sqlite3.connect('Gagan\French.db') SO i dont kow how to associate